# I Retained Select Option Value on First Dropdown but not Second or Third

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have 3 form select drop downs and have successfully retained the first select value after page loads, but am unable to get the second and third select values to be retained.

I'm using JavaScript and Jquery only for this.

I've tried over and over and finally got to bring my code here to see if someone more advanced can point out what I'm not doing correctly.

```
<form id="form">
  <select id="select0" type="text">
    <option type="text" value="" >make</option>
    <option type="text" value="ford" >ford</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select1" type="text">
    <option type="text" value="" >model</option>
    <option type="text" value="mustang" >mustang</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select2" type="text">
    <option type="text" value="">year</option>
    <option type="text" value="1967" >1967</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>the

// JavaScript
var storeMake = sessionStorage.getItem("themake");
var storeModel = sessionStorage.getItem("themodel");
var storeYear = sessionStorage.getItem("theyear");
var make = $("#form #select0");
var model = $("#form #select1");
var year = $("#form #select2");
if(storeMake != undefined || storeMake != null){
    make.find(":selected").removeAttr("selected");
    make.find("option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == storeMake) {
            $(this).attr("selected", true);
        }
    });
}
if(storeModel != undefined || storeModel != null){
    model.find(":selected").removeAttr("selected");
    model.find("option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == storeModel) {
            $(this).attr("selected", true);
        }
    });
}
if(storeYear != undefined || storeYear != null){
    year.find(":selected").removeAttr("selected");
    year.find("option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == storeYear) {
            $(this).attr("selected", true);
        }
    });
}

make.change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("themake", make.val());
});

model.change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("themodel", model.val());
});

year.change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("theyear", year.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) method can be used to set the value of a select. This will replace each `if` statement.

Try the code below. The snippet will not work in Stack Overflow because sessionStorage is disabled.

```js
var storeMake = sessionStorage.getItem("themake"),
    storeModel = sessionStorage.getItem("themodel"),
    storeYear = sessionStorage.getItem("theyear");

$("#select0").val(storeMake).change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("themake", $(this).val());
});
$("#select1").val(storeModel).change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("themodel", $(this).val());
});
$("#select2").val(storeYear).change(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem("theyear", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <select id="select0">
    <option value="">make</option>
    <option value="ford">ford</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="">model</option>
    <option value="mustang">mustang</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select2">
    <option value="">year</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

A few added notes:

- The `type` attribute is not needed on `select` or `option` elements.
- `$("#form #select0")` can  updated to `$("#select0")` since the id will be unique. Same with select1 and select2.

Comment: do you mean like this?
`make.change(function () { sessionStorage.setItem(make.val(themake)); });`

Comment: @Mike I edited my post to include the full code snippet. Does this solution work for you?